# Colorbox doesn't execute PHP code in AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, css, modal-dialog, colorbox

I have a PHP file and want it load in a [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) modal popup via AJAX but the PHP code inside of the file doesn't get executed (normal HTML tags like divs are visible only if I remove all PHP stuff). I have no idea why this is happening.

I can see e.g. the constants' names (like EP_AVATAR_RESTRICTIONS) but not their content (in this case it's just text).

My colorbox code:

```
$(".edit_avatar_link").colorbox({
        initialWidth:'386',
        initialHeight:'528',
        innerWidth:'386',
        innerHeight:'528',
        href: "<?php echo $setting['site_url'];?>/includes/forms/avatar_form2.php",
        fixed:true,
        scrolling:false,
        transition:'none',

        onComplete: function(){
            $("#cboxLoadedContent").appendTo("#cboxContent");

            var title = 'Edit Avatar';
            $('#cboxTitle').text(title);
        }
    });
```

My PHP-file (avatar_form2.php):

```
<?php defined( 'AVARCADE_' ) or die( '' ); // Security ?>
<div id="edit_avatar_content">
<div class="edit_profile_header"><?php echo EP_EDIT_AVATAR;?></div>
<div class="edit_avatar_container">
    <div class="edit_profile_lable"><img src="<?php echo $user['avatar'];?>" width="75" height="75"></div>
    <div class="edit_avatar_element">
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1" method="post" action="?task=edit_profile&done=avatar">
            <input name="new_id" type="hidden" id="new_id" value="<?php echo $new_id;?>" />
            <span class="style1"><?php echo EP_AVATAR_UP;?></span>
            <input name="img_file" type="file" id="img_file" size="50" /> <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="<?php echo EP_AVATAR_BUTTON;?>"/>
            <?php echo EP_AVATAR_RESTRICTIONS;?>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what php file is it exactly?

Comment: The code I posted above (avatar_form2.php).

Comment: Are you generating your js via php? Otherwise or is it its own external JS file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normal that you don't get anything. Your colorbox calls a programatically protected php file.

This line of code is causing it:

```
<?php defined( 'AVARCADE_' ) or die( '' ); // Security ?>
```

This is a direct access protection so that you can not directly access this file. One makes that to only make it includable from other php files that do a DEFINE('AVARCADE_','something');

either remove that line of code or make another php file that defines the AVARCADE_ constant and then include the vatar_form2.php in that file

Comment: I removed it but still doesn't work correctly. I can see in my browser all my constants' names (i.e. the name of the constants like EP_AVATAR_RESTRICTIONS instead of their content).

Comment: that is because this file doesn't set the EP_AVATAR_RESTRICTIONS constant. it is being set somewhere else. it looks to me like you are using some kind of MVC Framework and you are accessing the form the totally wrong way.

Comment: Ok. How would you access such constants in colorbox? The constants are defined in a file called 'English.php' (in a different folder called 'translations'). I have no idea how to access them...

Comment: what MVC is it? Normally you would do it the same way you would access a normal page but instead with another view than the standard view that is made especially for ajax requests